# Do The Traces Genetic Diseases Remain in families?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, molecular-evolution

I know that there are certain diseases that are predominant on genes. But, is there any sort of surety that if parents are suffering from a disorder then their offspring has to suffer from the same. Like my dad is schizophrenic so will I become the victim of the same mental disorder?

Comment: just like any genetically affected traits (e.g. height), there is on average greater resemblance between parents and offspring than between two randomly chosen people. If a parent has a genetically controlled disease there is an increased likelihood of it developing in the children but it is by no means a guarantee (even for dominant mendelian traits if mutation occurs). Few things are entirely genetically determined.

Comment: In the case of schizophrenia, it has always been evident that there is a genetic factor. However it has not been identified. More recent hypotheses suggest [epigenetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigenetics) mechanisms. Meaning the trait can be inherited, but is very sensitive to short-term environmental changes.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Your question reveals that you probably don't know the concepts of Mendelian segregation/dominance/additivity/pleiotropy and epistasis. You should check out those terms on wikipedia. Also You will probably want to increase your understanding of heritability. [Here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16858/are-people-genetically-predisposed-to-being-interested-in-specific-fields-ideas/16862#16862) is an answer that link to 4 other posts that talk about heritability.