# What is the Genetic Cause of Homosexuality?

Tags: genetics, homosexuality

So, I'm just wondering about this because I read the following in my Biology textbook about fruit fly genes:

> "Normal male and female flies express distinct forms of the *fru* gene. When females are genetically manipulated to express the male form of *fru*, they court other females, performing the role normally played by the male..."

Out of curiosity, have any studies been conducted to see what causes homosexuality? Is there a similar gene in humans that, if randomly altered, causes attraction to same-sex individuals?

EDIT: a similar post exists, but nobody provided an answer related to the poster's question.

Comment: The phrasing suggest some misunderstanding of what `genetic cause` could mean. On [this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16858/are-people-genetically-predisposed-to-being-interested-in-specific-fields-ideas/16862#16862) I linked a number of posts where I explain the concepts of heritability (which is related to this misunderstanding even if it is not necessarily obvious to you right now).